# display divs inline-block in 2 columns without vertical gaps

Tags: html, css

Quite a simple problem, but I can't seem to find a solution (using pure css, I'd like to avoid things like Isotope). I have a 2 column grid, the divs displayed inline-block so they fill the `.wrap` div, problem is though because the divs have variable heights, there are massive gaps below the divs in the right hand column.

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/ntyLg/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}

.test {
    width: 240px;
    background-color: orange;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.test:nth-child(odd) {
    height: 200px;
}
.test:nth-child(even) {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Any CSS only solutions to such a problem? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: and how would you wish it be? what do you want in that 'empty space'?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no css-only solution if the heights truly are variable.  You're looking at either setting a height in your css to force them to be the same height, or some javascript to do some quick calcs/adjustments based on the height in the given row.

Comment: @cale_b that's not totally true, he can use some faux column techniques, or CSS table layout.. it just depends on what he want to do with that empty space. still waiting for his answer on that one..

Comment: @watson [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) is a jQuery plugin that makes it fantastically easy to have a variable number of columns of unique sized divs (MIT license for personal use, paid license for commercial). Basically, the Pintrest style. See also [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) (open source for all).

Comment: True - forgot about table-cell layout options: http://ajaxian.com/archives/display-table

Comment: I don't understand this problem at all. It literally does exactly what the his code tells it to do. If you specify the right columns to have a height of `100px`, you can't be surprised when they do.

Comment: Maybe multi-column? http://jsfiddle.net/pzxVE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is you don't actually have two columns, so you need something like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/ntyLg/2/)

[Here is it working with different css](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/ntyLg/4/)

Or you could have a `.column` class if you wanted:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but what if the 2 big div are in the same column?

Comment: This doesn't allow for variable heights.  The same problem will exist, you've just made the heights equal and so it looks right.

Comment: @watson apparently, you didn't understand the question.

Comment: @watson You missed the point that he doesn't want a large difference between the height of the left and right column.

Comment: and now you're downvoting my posts.. good for you. very mature.

Comment: This forced number of columns makes responsive designs much harder (pretty hard to use `@media` to make the HTML you have into a non-two-column layout), but it's a good approach if you know you're always going to only have 2 columns. have an upvote.

Comment: @watson thanks for your answer—although visually they are what I'm after, I'd rather not split the columns into separate divs (if possible)